# What is the furthest date that can be represented by a JS Date?

Tags: javascript

`new Date(Infinity)` is too far, and so is `new Date(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - 1)`.

I need this so I can run astronomical simulations on a Node cluster.

JK, I'm just messing around, and SO imposed a minimum question length.

Looks like [RFC3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) doesn't specify a maximum.

Comment: From Wiki: The latest time that can be represented in Unix's signed 32-bit integer time format is 03:14:07 UTC on Tuesday, 19 January 2038 (2,147,483,647 seconds after 1 January 1970)

Comment: Yeah, but our Numbers aren't 32bit integers. According to the spec linked from the question I accidentally duplicated, the max date is approximately 285,616 years after epoch (1970).

Comment: So, sometime before 2038, we must rewrite all critical software in Javascript ;)

Comment: Probably... y2K38.

Thing is that integers in Javascript are still floats technically. parseInt/Float functions are just for convenience to remove decimal places. 

There are some libs which try to simulate big numbers functionality, but are mostly based on strings.